# React select - How to filter selection based on picked option of other selection field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-select

I am using react-select and I want to show matching city pairs (certain origins have only certain destinations) in 2 fields. Ive been thinking a lot and can't come up with a way to filter the destination selection field based on what was picked in the origin selection field. Anyone has any ideas or any tipps?Thanks!!

My response is an array with objects. each object has (among other things) the origin city and a destination city:

```
...
{OriginDestinationLocations:{DestinationLocation:{CityName:'Orlando'}, OriginLocation:{CityName:'Miami'}}},
 {OriginDestinationLocations:{DestinationLocation:{CityName:'Orlando'}, OriginLocation:{CityName:'Chicago'}}},
 {OriginDestinationLocations:{DestinationLocation:{CityName:'Las Vegas'}, OriginLocation:{CityName:'Miami'}}}
....
// so here (pretending that would be the full list) when I pick Orlando as origin in the 1st selection field, I should only see Miami and Chicago in the second field.

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      from:[],
      to:[]
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
   cityPairs().then(response => {
        let from = [];
        let to = [];
    // here its wrong to separate destination and origin as origin needs to stay 'connected' to the matching destinations but I just don't know what else to do. if I push objects with always matching origins/destinations into 1 array, I was thinking it would create so many pair, that can't be right in terms of performance etc. or would that be the only way?
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            from.push(response[i].DestinationLocation.CityName);
            to.push(response[i].OriginLocation.CityName);
        }
        this.setState({
            to: to,
            from: from
        })
    })
}

 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 }
render(){
  return (
  <div>
      <Select
          name="form-field-name"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          clearable={this.state.clearable}
          searchable={this.state.searchable}
          labelKey='name'
          valueKey='cityCode'
          options={this.state.to}
       />
  </div>
  )
}
}
```

-added parts:

```
 cityPairs().then(response => {
        this.setState({
            routes: response
                .reduce((dest, x) => Object.assign({}, dest, {
                  ...
                }), {})
        });
    }).then(res => {
        var result = [];
        var r = this.state.routes;
        for (var key in r) {
            result.push(key)
        }
        this.setState({
            originRoutes: result.map(x => ({
                name: x,
                value: x
            } ))
        })
    })

//as I believe  const routes  = this.state.routes[this.state.selected]; should be changed to

const originRoutes  = this.state.originRoutes[this.state.selected];
    const options = !originRoutes ? [] : originRoutes.map(x => ({
        name:  x,
        value: x
} ));

            <Select            
                onChange={this.onChange}
                options={this.state.originRoutes}
            />
            <Select                   
               onChange={this.onChange}
               options={options}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this solution is not containing right now is sending requests again and again. It just loads data from the API initially. But I think this is how the API itself is working right now. Should be changed if the data is too big.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            routes: []
        });

        cityPairs().then(response => {
            // result is an object with a key of the origin name and a list of destination names
            this.setState({
                routes: response
                    .reduce((dest, x) => Object.assign({}, dest, {
                        // multiple lines at best :-D
                        [x.OriginLocation.CityName]: dest[x.OriginLocation.CityName] ? dest[x.OriginLocation.CityName].concat([x.DestinationLocation.CityName]) : [x.DestinationLocation.CityName]
                    }), {})
            });
        });
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            selected: event.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        const routes  = this.state.routes[this.state.selected];
        const options = !routes ? [] : routes.map(x => ({
            name:  x,
            value: x
        }));

        return(
            <div>
                <Select
                    ...
                    onChange={::this.onChange}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry if I wasn't clear enough with my question maybe! When I make a request, I receive data (city pairs). There will be tausends of different cities (origin as well as destinations I am receiving). However, for example an origin lets say London might have only 5 matching destinations while other origins have 50 etc. When I now type in London into the first option field, there shouldn't be all destinations be shown, but ONLY the 5 matching ones for London.

Comment: Updated my solution. Does this help?

Comment: thank you! It doesn't work so far, I checked the first part (reduce((dest, x) => Object.assign({}, dest, { etc) and the result of this is that Im getting back objects with arrays which only show one city/ once or multiple times {Amsterdam:[(13) ["Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdam", etc.]}

Comment: Was my fault. Used OriginLocation everywhere. Updated my answer once again ^^

Comment: Hey thank you! So the first dropdown wasn't showing anything and I added to your code (please see my edit), and then it was showing, however, every time I pick one city, im getting the error value is not defined, so that also the destinations drop down never shows any values. Thanks for helping out!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160733/discussion-between-tobias-and-javascripting).